# A TLS certificate is required in EventStore. What should I do?

Tags: .net-core, certificate, tls1.2, eventstoredb

I was following this [tutorial](https://eventstore.com/docs/getting-started/index.html?tabs=tabid-1%2Ctabid-dotnet-client%2Ctabid-dotnet-client-connect%2Ctabid-4) and when I ran this command:

```
EventStore.ClusterNode.exe --db ./db --log ./logs
```

I got the exception shown here:

[image]

Since I am just playing with this software, I cannot contact their support. I would avoid for now setting to development mode.

I am not using Docker, just plain cmd in administrator mode on a Windows 10 (Home Edition) x64.

I never worked correctly with any certificates, and after googling I got stuck. What can I do to fix this? It is not a matter of programming, rather something of setting up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use EventStoreDB 20.6 using the previous release docs. The banner on the top of the page shows it:

[image]

I have to admit that new docs don't explain the certificate story well enough (or, like, almost not at all), but the C# gRPC client [Quick Tour](https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/dotnet/generated/v20.6.0/getting-started/quick-tour.html) gives you some instructions for Docker. I'd say that even if you aren't using Docker, you'd be much better off if you do since it's what we will document first in details because Docker is what most developers use.

Hence that the mentioned Quick Tour uses 20.6.1 nightly build, where we introduced the insecure mode and that's what the tutorial uses. The stable 20.6.1 release will be out in a week or two.

The 20.6 [release notes](https://eventstore.com/blog/event-store-20.6.0-release/) have quite a lot of information as well, including the TLS/SSL story.

Comment: @LiviuSosu if you got your issue resolved, please accept the solution so others would know that it is the right answer.

Comment: thanks again for your answer. Docker does not run on Windows home edition and, the way I see it, for both versons 20.6.1 and 5.0.9 Docker is required. If is not possible then is not possible, I was just exploring stuff as I've alreay mentioned in the question. Do I need some paid accound for HTTP api version?

Comment: If you don't use Docker, you can instal EventStoreDB using Chocolatey and run it with `Insecure` mode https://developers.eventstore.com/server/20.6/server/installation/windows.htmll https://developers.eventstore.com/server/20.6/server/security/configuration.html#running-without-security

Comment: Alright, thanks! But n order to write some C# code, I need Docker, right? https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/dotnet/generated/v20.6.1/getting-started/#writing-an-event

Comment: No, why? Docker just gives you an easy way to spin up the server locally without installing anything on the machine. You don't need Docker for writing code.

Comment: Once again thank you for your support! You helpme me installing the server. That was my question about. But now I want to connect to this server that I installed on my machine. Shoud I run a command or something? In your documentation - I hope the link will work: https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/dotnet/generated/v20.6.1/getting-started/#setup-the-certificates-and-running-the-server says that I need to connect to http://localhost:2113 .Shouldn't I somehw start the server first? If you wnat I can write another SO question

Comment: Is there a way that I could find out the port number on which the server is running after installation?

Comment: In the docs, which I referenced. The HTTP port is 2113.

Comment: I already tried. I guess I need to start the server, no just to onstall it. I get an exception saying that a connection could not be created. "Could not connect because the destination computer refused to connect. SocketException: Could not connect because the target computer refused to connect".  don't know how to start the server, assuming this is the issue.

Comment: ESDB never installs a Windows service, if you are on Windows. Indeed, you need to start the server manually or use something like NSSM.

Comment: @Alexey the link is broken https://developers.eventstore.com/clients/dotnet/generated/v20.6.0/getting-started/quick-tour.html

Answer (score 0):

I use  `--insecure` tag when start `EventStore.ClusterNode.exe` with cmd like this:

> EventStore.ClusterNode.exe --insecure

Answer (score 0):

The following command will start the EventStoreDB node using default HTTP port, without security.

```
docker run --name esdb-node -it -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113 eventstore/eventstore:latest --insecure --run-projections=All
```

[Clicl here for more details](https://developers.eventstore.com/server/v20.10/installation.html#uninstall-1)